# Firebase Remote Config doesn't work with NodeJS in Unit Test

Tags: node.js, reactjs, firebase, firebase-remote-config

I created a function that uses Firebase Remote Config. Everything works fine with `npm run start`. But when I tried to run all unit test cases, it doesn't work anymore.
Here are the codes that I used to import the library:

```
// This import loads the firebase namespace along with all its type information.
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';

// These imports load individual services into the firebase namespace.
import 'firebase/remote-config';
```

But then, when I try to run the unit test with the command `npm run test`. It through an exception:

```
Test suite failed to run

(node:18099) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: indexedDB is not defined
(node:18099) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 2)
```

Here is the screenshot: 
[image]

Do you guys have any idea about how to resolve this?
Thanks.